# Detecting change in value read by scanf

Tags: c, if-statement, while-loop, text-files, scanf

For an assignment we are supposed to read in a list of dates and associated values (temperatures) from a text document. Values in each line are separated by commas.

Example data:

```
dd,mm,yyyy,x,y,z,w
01,01,2011,1.1,5.2,6.5,7.5
02,01,2011,2.1,5.2,6.1,1.1
03,01,2011,4.5,2.5,6.1,2.1
...
30,01,2011,4.1,6.1,6.1,2.1
01,02,2011,2.5,6.1,7.1,6.3
```

So far I have implemented a loop to read each line:

```
while(scanf("%d,%d,%d,%f,%f,%f,%f", &dd, &mm, &yyyy, &x, &y, &z, &w) == 7)
{
}
```

We're given the assumption that there are no errors in the document, and no duplicate dates.

However, there may be missing entries (not each month have complete data; missing days).

I am having trouble detecting if each month's data (mm) is a complete month or only a partial month.

Eg: 31 days in March 2011. If I have 31 entries from March, I need to print 'Full month', otherwise if there are missing days I have to print 'Partial month'.

So far I have been using `if(mm==1){}` statements to separate each month inside the `while(scanf(...))` loop and then incrementing them in separate variables, then comparing it with the amount of days in a complete month, but I don't know how to implement it so it detects that mm has changed from the previous line (new month) and perform a certain action (e.g.: calculations)

Sorry if this is confusing!

We have not been taught arrays yet, only operations, loops and functions.

Comment: We understand that you have a big homework to solve. Please try to reduce your requirements or break it up and get answers one by one.

Comment: Can we assume that the data is grouped by month, that is all dates for the month of January will be together.

Comment: @Ozair, Thanks for reading! Yes, forgot to mention that the textfile is in order, all of January will be grouped together, with the days incrementing each new line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

keep prev month value somewhere; finalize monthly related computations and reset the monthly counters when the month you are reading is higher than prev month

```
int curmonth = 1;
int dd,mm,yyy;
float x,y,z,w;
float xtotal = 0,ytotal = 0,ztotal = 0,wtotal = 0;
while(scanf("%d,%d,%d,%f,%f,%f,%f", &dd, &mm, &yyyy, &x, &y, &z, &w))==7 {
    if (mm == curmonth) {
        //add to current counters
        ztotal+=z;
        ytotal+=y;
        xtotal+=y;
        wtotal+=w;
    } else {
        if (mm < curmonth) 
            //not the expected order as per specs so better die now
            exit(1);
        printf("month=%d,my_calculations=%f,%f,%f,%f\n",xtotal,ytotal,ztotal,wtotal);
        xtotal = ytotal = ztotal = wtotal = 0; curmonth=mm;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @adirau, thanks for the sample code. The text file given may not always start at January (but still ascending). I'll give it a go at making the code take the first mm value from the first line. Thanks again!

Comment: i'm sure you can improve it from here on as per your real needs/requirements; cheers!

Comment: sorry for the bother, I'm using your format and made it take the value of the first line, but it is omitting the last month altogether, and will only print out the last month if there is a 'dummy line' at the end of the file. I'm guessing it has something to do with EOF?

Comment: Please disregard the prev comment, managed to get the answer with posted Q, thank you for before!

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I don't think you want "separate variables" for the different months. Why not an array, indexed by month (i.e. mm)? This will probably reduce your code length by an order of magnitude. Oh, you haven't been taught arrays yet.

Second, at the top of the loop set a 'last_mm' variable. This will be the value of mm last time you went through the loop. Initialize it to -1 or something. When last_mm and mm are different, you know the month has changed. At the bottom of the loop, set last_mm to mm.

In general, this is the way to detect changes during loops.

Comment: Thank you for the tips. We're actually going to cover arrays soon so I guess it wouldn't hurt to read ahead. Thanks for your second tip, I think I have an idea now on what to do.

Answer (score 0):

The following code is untested, but something like this should do the trick for you without arrays. I hope you know switch/case already.

```
//Keep track of which month we are fetching data for
int currentMonth = 1;
//Number of days for which data have been read for the current month
int numberOfDaysInCurrentMonth = 0;
//Full = 1 would represent if all data is available for currentMonth
int full = 0;
//This is set to 1 only when data is read for a month different to currentMonth
int monthChanged = 0;

while(scanf("%d,%d,%d,%f,%f,%f,%f", &dd, &mm, &yyyy, &x, &y, &z, &w) == 7)
{
    // If month changed in last iteration  
    if(monthChanged == 1) {
        //Check if full = 1 print "Full Month" to output
        if(full == 1) {
             printf("Full Month");
        //Else there was partial data 
        } else {
             printf("Partial Month");
        }

        //Once the output is on the screen set this back to 0, so it will be set to 
        //1 only when month changes next time.
        monthChanged = 0;
    }

    //If currentMonth is the same as mm, just add 1 to number of days in this month
    //for which data is provided  
    if(currentMonth == mm) {
        ++numberOfDaysInCurrentMonth;

    //otherwise
    } else { 
        switch(currentMonth) {
            //In case the month is January, March, May, July, August, October, December
            case 1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 10, 12:
                //Number of days should be 31 for full to be 1
                if(numberOfDaysInCurrentMonth == 31)
                     full = 1;
            break;
            //In case the month is February
            case 2:
                //Number of days should be 28 for month to be full 
                //(ignoring leap years)  
                if(numberOfDaysInCurrentMonth == 28)
                     full = 1;
            break;
            //In case the month is April, June, September, November
            case 4, 6, 9, 11:
                //Number of days should be 28 for month to be full 
                if(numberOfDaysInCurrentMonth == 30)
                     full = 1;
            break;     
        }
        //Now that we have set what we desired, set
        //currentMonth to mm 
        currentMonth = mm;
        //The month just changed, otherwise we would not have been in this part
        of the code
        monthChanged = 1;
        //Number of days in current month starts from 1
        numberOfDaysInCurrentMonth = 1;
    }

    //Do whatever you are doing with data here
}
```